# Get timestamp in PySpark from GregorianCalendar

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, gregorian-calendar

The Spark Dataframe has a column where the value is GregorianCalendar as below:

`java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2017,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=1,SECOND=52,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]`

How can I get the exact value of timestamp from this?
The actual value of the column is "2017-07-18 09:01:52".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace)?

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2017,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=1,SECOND=52,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]',)],
    ['GregorianCalendar']
)
pattern = r'(?:.*)YEAR=(\d+).+?MONTH=(\d+).+?DAY_OF_MONTH=(\d+).+?HOUR=(\d+).+?MINUTE=(\d+).+?SECOND=(\d+).+'
df = df.withColumn('timest', F.regexp_replace('GregorianCalendar', pattern, '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6').cast('timestamp'))
df.show()
# +--------------------+-------------------+
# |   GregorianCalendar|             timest|
# +--------------------+-------------------+
# |java.util.Gregori...|2017-07-18 09:01:52|
# +--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This was a life-saver Answer. Thank you very much!!

Comment: There may be a problem with this - months in java.util.GregorianCalendar are zero indexed, so in the example above, the date in the column is actually 2017-08-18.

Comment: Yup this solution doesnt work since month is zero indexed.